# Copying excel range to powerpoint with vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, powerpoint

I'm tring to copy a range of an open excel spreadsheet to an open powerpoint. When i run the code, i get the message " Compile error - User defined type not defined" I'm pretty new and i don't know how to fix it.

Sub Importdatau()

```
'declare the variables
    Dim activePowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim rng As Range

 'Copy Range from Excel
```

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:m30")

```
 'Look for existing instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Show the PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True

    'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
        rng.Copy
        activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select


    'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0

        activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
        activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 505
```

Comment: Did you set a reference (VBE > Tools > Reference) to the Microsoft PowerPoint xx.x Object Library?

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks for your reply. Yes, reference was set.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: I receive the message from the "Sub" at the beginning which becomes yellow, and it does not display any other line

Comment: Some other part of the code should have been highlighted in blue as well, probably `cht As Excel.ChartObject`, which would mean that you're missing a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library.  Where are you running the code from?  If you're running it from PowerPoint, you'll need to set a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library.

Comment: I am running the code from excel. i tried to run other macros (downloading them from internet) and they work (reference being set). that said, i am really lost, i need a simple copy paste on an open slide but i'm really stuck :/

Comment: Try running it again, but this time though, when it highlights the procedure's declaration line in yellow, check to see if anything gets highlighted in blue.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a regular module in a sample workbook, set a reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library, made sure that a PowerPoint presentation file is already open, and ran it without any errors.

Comment: Dominic, thank you so much for your patience. I thought I only had to set up the reference once and that was it. I set it in this spreadsheet as well and now it works! feel pretty dumb now :/ thank you so much!!